# Access automapper from other class library in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using asp.net core 2.0. I have DataAccess project and 20 API service project in my solution. And this number increasing every day. I will use AutoMapper. But I don't want to add automapper from NuGet for all projects. So, I want to add to the only DataAccess solution and adding profiles to DataAccess solution. And I want to call from API project by writing "mapper.Map(originalObject)". We can add Automapper to API project by adding startup.cs. But my DataAccess project is a class library. So it hasn't got startup.cs. How can I do this and can I access automapper from service projects? (I don't want to add automapper from NuGet to API)

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#profile-instances

Comment: I think you have two problems. One is hiding the AutoMapper from other projects and second is initializing the AutoMapper. For the first one, you can hide AutoMapper behind an interface of your own, or use a static helper class. For the second one, you again use a static constructor approach for initializng the AutoMapper.

Comment: Yes. But i don't know how to do this? So, i am looking for sample code or project for .net core. @NthDeveloper

Comment: Where should i add MapperConfiguration and how to start MapperConfiguration 
 what is shown in the documentation @LucianBargaoanu?

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/master/README.md) and [this](https://github.com/jbogard/ContosoUniversityCore). And of course, research :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @LucianBargaoanu :). But my problem is adding Automapper to class library project. These example adding to console app. I can do it with no problem. But i was looking for is adding to class library project for generic solution like NthDeveloper's said in above comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be many solutions to this problem, I suggest only two of them and these aproaches may also change depending on your choice and scenario. Whether your helper class knows all the types that will be mapped or other user libraries need to register their own POCO classes, whether you prefer creating a mapper... You may also want to cache mappers and return it if it requested again.

Simple code samples are as follows

```
class Foo
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Bar
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //First approach usage
    Bar _bar1 = MapperHelper.MapFrom<Bar>(new Foo() { Name = "bbbbb" });

    //Second approach usage
    IMyMapper _myMapper = MapperHelper.GetMapperFor<Foo, Bar>();
    Bar _bar2 = _myMapper.MapFrom<Bar>(new Foo() { Name = "aaaAAA" });

    //Third approach usage
    Bar _bar3 = MapperHelper.Map<Bar, Foo>(new Foo() { Name = "cccc" });
}

public interface IMyMapper
{
    T MapFrom<T>(object entity);
}

class MyMapper : IMyMapper
{
      IMapper mapper;

      public MyMapper(IMapper mapper)
      {
            this.mapper = mapper;
      }

      public T MapFrom<T>(object entity)
      {
           return mapper.Map<T>(entity);
      }
}

public static class MapperHelper
{
     static IMapper staticMapper;

    static MapperHelper()
    {
         var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
         cfg.CreateMap<Foo, Bar>();
         });

        staticMapper = config.CreateMapper();
     }

     //First approach, create a mapper and use it from a static method
     public static T MapFrom<T>(object entity)
     {
           return staticMapper.Map<T>(entity);
     }

     //Second approach (if users need to use their own types which are not known by this project)
     //Create you own mapper interface ans return it
     public static IMyMapper GetMapperFor<TSource, TDestination>()
     {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
                cfg.CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>();
            });

            var _mapper = config.CreateMapper();

            return new MyMapper(_mapper);
     }

     //Third sample, create and use mapper inside a static helper method
     //This is for mapping foreign types that this project does not 
     //include (e.g POCO or model types in other projects)
     public static TDestination Map<TDestination, TSource>(TSource entity)
     {
         var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
               cfg.CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>();
            });

            var _mapper = config.CreateMapper();

            return _mapper.Map<TDestination>(entity);
     }
 }
```

First one creates the configuration for known types and uses this mapper.
Second one creates a mapper and returns it in a wrapper class.
Third one creates and uses a mapper for mapping operation and only returns the mapped object.

Most people do not like static classes and methods since they cause strict unwanted dependencies, they can not be replaced easily. So, creating factory or utility classes, registering them to a dependency injection container and in jecting them where needed is preferred.

Comment: Thanks a lot @NthDeveloper. I spent hours with this. This is what i was looking for. But the only problem is while calling function in your "Main" function. Because we are writing a lot of code. Can we write this with only one row like ***** static void Main (){  MapperHelper.Map<Bar>(new Foo() { Name = "aaa" }) } *****

Comment: @Hasan, I have added some more usage examples. Please check the first approach usage sample and the third one, hope these helps.

Comment: Third approach is my looking for. Thank you very very much for your interest @NthDeveloper

Answer (score 0):

Shared project:

```
namespace App.Shared.Common;

public class AutoMapper : Profile
{
    public AutoMapper()
    {
        CreateMap<Client, ClientDto>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

Main project:

```
namespace App.API.Common;

public class MyAutoMapper : App.Shared.Common.AutoMapper
{
    public MyAutoMapper() : base() { }
}
```

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));
```

This work form me.

Comment: This works because you are inheriting the "base" class Automapper. This would mean that if you would have seperate files for all kind of different profiles, you would have to create multiple classes in your main project as well.. Any other alternatives?